# Вывод текста вместо формы после отправки

Tags: javascript, jquery

По нажатию на кнопку "записаться" у меня всплывает `alert`. Вместо этого нужно, чтобы на место формы, с которой отправлялась заявка, выходил обычный блок с текстом. Что для этого нужно прописать? `document.write`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.php",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            $(this).find("input").val("");
            alert("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
            $("#form").trigger("reset");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить форму текстом можно с помощью метода [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $("#form1");
  $form.submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "send.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    //}).done(function() {
    }).fail(function() {
      $form.replaceWith("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`done` заменён на `fail` для работоспособности в сниппете.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!